# Bootstrap, Portfolios, & Modal

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to get the modal to show up on a portfolio click, but it does not work.. But when I use a regular button, the modal shows up.

**Portfolio button that doesn't work:**

```
<a href="#myModal1" class="portfolio-box">
  <img src="img/portfolio/1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
     <div class="portfolio-box-caption">
          <div class="portfolio-box-caption-content">
             <div class="project-name">
                   School
             </div>
          </div>
     </div>
</a>
```

**Button code that works:**

```
 <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal1" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">School Backpack</a>
```

**Modal:**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">School Backpack</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      ...
    </div>
```

Comment: Where is `data-toggle="modal"` in your portfolio button that doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `data-toggle="modal"` attribute, which bootstrap needs to know what to do when you click the button.

Your button code should be:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal1" class="portfolio-box">
```

Hope this helps!